# Search list of object based on another list of object c#

Tags: c#, list, search, object

i have this class:

```
   class Ean
   {
        public string Code{ get; set; }
   }

   class Article
   {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Ean> BarCode { get; set; }
   }


   List<Article> arts = new List<Article>();
   List<Ean> eans = new List<Ean>();
```

I have a list of two objects. I need to check if in the list "arts.BarCode" there is one of the codes in the list eans. How can I do to make this search returns a Boolean value? 
Any help would be great! Thanks!

something like this would be perfect:

```
bool hasCheese = arts.Any(a => a.Name == "Cheese");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you *could* just use:

```
bool hasCode = arts.Any(a => a.BarCode.Intersect(eans).Any());
```

That's assuming that *either* you want to treat each `Ean` object individually, *or* you've actually overridden `Equals` and `GetHashCode` appropriately.

It would be more efficient to create a set though:

```
var set = new HashSet<Ean>(eans);
bool hasCode = arts.Any(a => a.BarCode.Any(e => set.Contains(e)));
```

As an alternative approach, you could flatten your list to basically be a sequence of barcodes:

```
bool hasCode = arts.SelectMany(a => a.BarCode)
                   .Intersect(eans)
                   .Any();
```

That's actually probably the cleanest approach, as you don't care about *which* article has the matching barcode.

Comment: If i use the first give me an error : Value can not be null.
Parameter name: first . Why ? Thanks

Comment: @enzop92: Well that suggests that one of your references is null. However, as you haven't even said which method call is failing, it's hard to tell you which... I suggest you look at your data carefully.

Comment: Jon Thank you so much.. U are very kind !

Answer (score 2):

```
arts.SelectMany(a => a.BarCode).Intersect(eans).Any()
```

should be an efficient way of doing this, if I understand your problem correctly.

```
arts.SelectMany(a => a.BarCode)
```

flattens all the BarCode collections to an `Enumerable<Ean>`, which you can then intersect with your other collection and see if anything is left.