# How to create a list of objects based on a value that the object contains in a list of objects C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm looking for a help. 
I'm working an exercise based on MVC.
My model contains 2 classes. The DVD and the Category

```
public class DVD
{
public int ID
{ get; set; }

public string Title
{ get; set; }

public decimal Price
{ get; set; }

public int Quantity
{ get; set; }

public int Duration
{ get; set; }

public string Image
{ get; set; }

public virtual IList<Category> Categories_List
{ get; set; }}
```

Now the Category which is a method contains the following

```
 public class Category
    {
    public int Id
    { get; set; }

    public string Title
    { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<DVD> DVDs
    { get; set; } }
```

Both DVD and Category are under the Model folder.
What I want to do is to create a list in my controller of the Category (inside the method of public ActionResult Details(int id = 0) )
to collect all the dvds which are in the category with the id 1 for example.

I found something simillar but I have problem when I have to check if the DVD's category id is the same with the one I'm looking for.

[Search list of object based on another list of object c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17348754/search-list-of-object-based-on-another-list-of-object-c-sharp)

Can anyone help me to do it?
Thank you

Comment: _"Now the Category which is a method"_ do you mean _"class"_ instead?

Comment: Is this plain classes/objects, or are these representing many-to-many DB relationships using EF, or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use LINQ `Where`. This will return call of the movies that match a particular category:

```
var moviesMatchingCategory = _masterMovieList.Where(ml => ml.Categories_List.Any(cl => cl.Id == categoryIdToCompare)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use linq this will help:

```
public IEnumerable<DVD> FindDvdByCategoryId(int categoryId, IEnumerable<DVD> dvdEnumerable)
    {
        return dvdEnumerable.Where(dvd => dvd.Categories_List.Any(c => c.Id == categoryId)).ToList();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<DVD> list = dvds.Where(x=>x.Categories_List.Contains(y=>y.Id==Id)).ToList();
```

Try the above.